# Is there a way to map key range in VIM?

Tags: vim

I would like to map any key to a custom function call. The function will determine what to do based on the specific key pressed, or the last key sequence.

Is there a way to map a key range (e.g., "any key" or "a-z0-9")?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do this with a single mapping. The best you can do is a loop and a bunch of mappings. For example to remap all normal mode lower case characters:

```
for c in range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z'))
    execute 'nnoremap ' . nr2char(c) . ' :echo " Pressed: ' . nr2char(c) . '"<CR>'
endfor
```

If you want `[a-z0-9]` you need to use two `range()` calls to get the right key codes, since the key codes for the numbers and lowercase letters don't line up (See the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/)):

```
for c in range(char2nr('0'), char2nr('9')) + range(char2nr('a'), char2nr('z'))
    execute 'nnoremap ' . nr2char(c) . ' :echo " Pressed: ' . nr2char(c) . '"<CR>'
endfor
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to act on characters typed individually in INSERT mode, you can use the `InsertCharPre` event. For example:

```
autocmd InsertCharPre * call FilterChar()

function! FilterChar()
    if (v:char == 'a')
        let v:char = 'ouch'
        echo v:char
    endif
endfunction
```

This subverts inserting `a` by replacing it with `ouch`, on the fly, while also echoing the same text (which means you can do other stuff there, such as calling a function).